# SqlDataReader Case Sensitive

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2, case-sensitive

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    myDatabaseConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Emp where Fname = @Fname", myDatabaseConnection))
    {
        mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", NametextBox.Text);
        SqlDataReader DR1 = mySqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();
        if (DR1.Read())
        {
            MessagabeBox.Show("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

For example I have a Fname `Smith` in the database and then I type `Smith` in the NametextBox, the messageBox will show. But when I type `smith` or `SMITH`, it still reads. What will I do to make the reader case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the collation, eg.

```
Select * from Emp where Fname COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = @Fname
```